# Issues while setting up vespa on multiple docker containers

Tags: vespa

I have two dockers sitting on two different machines, both running the vespa. When I submit an application which have two nodes - vespa1 and vespa2 (resolved in /etc/hosts). I get the following error.

```
Uploading application '/vespa-eval/src/main/application/' using http://localhost:19071/application/v2/tenant/default/session?name=application
Session 6 for tenant 'default' created.
Preparing session 6 using
http://localhost:19071/application/v2/tenant/default/session/6/prepared
Request failed. HTTP status code: 400
Invalid application package: default.default: Error loading model:
Could not find host in the application's host system: 'vespa-container'. Hostsystem=host 'vespa1',host 'vespa2'
```

I do not have a problem when using only localhost.

hosts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hosts>
    <host name="vespa1">
    <alias>node0</alias>
</host>
    <host name="vespa2">
    <alias>node1</alias>
</host>
</hosts>
```

services.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<services version="1.0">

  <admin version="2.0">
    <adminserver hostalias="node0"/>
    <configservers>
      <configserver hostalias="node0"/>
    </configservers>
  </admin>

  <container id="container" version="1.0">
    <document-api />
    <search />
    <nodes>
      <node hostalias="node0" />
      <node hostalias="node1" />
    </nodes>
  </container>

  <content id="product" version="1.0">
    <redundancy>1</redundancy>
    <documents>
      <document type="product" mode="index" />
    </documents>
    <nodes>
      <node hostalias="node0" distribution-key="0" />
      <node hostalias="node1" distribution-key="1" />
    </nodes>
  </content>

</services>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a host named vespa-container is already deployed but not in the new application package. To debug, try

```
vespa-model-inspect hosts
```

on the config server and see if it lists the host. Maybe a good idea to try from scratch, I don't see anything wrong with the enclosed files. To clean the config server, search for

```
vespa-configserver-remove-state
```

in the documentation

Comment: I was seting it up with vespa-container as hostname. I was assuming if I modify the /etc/hosts it would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue, and fixed the error by replacing 'vespa-container' (below command) to the hostname of physical box. However, this caused a couple of other errors in rpc connection. Did you fix the problem yet? @aman.gupta

```
 docker run --detach --name vespa --hostname vespa-container --privileged \
  --volume $VESPA_SAMPLE_APPS:/vespa-sample-apps --publish 8080:8080 vespaengine/vespa
```